# Sort block of numbers into columns

Tags: bash, sorting

i have a file with alot of data written out of a simulation:

```
  0.00000000E+00
  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  
  0.93071889E-02
  0.14952319E-13  0.55746201E-11  0.89816722E-11  0.46833532E-11  0.14964636E-13
 -0.92995325E-47  0.79969902E-46  0.00000000E+00 -0.21442451-105 -0.86924526E-93
  0.00000000E+00 -0.85777333E-93  0.48179949-102  0.00000000E+00  
  0.18614378E-01
  0.12050471E-12  0.44928328E-10  0.72404536E-10  0.37744496E-10  0.12066634E-12
  0.25848493E-36 -0.13804858E-35  0.56376226E-83  0.20648121E-74 -0.89608567E-66
 -0.20861629E-76 -0.87854256E-66 -0.23574755E-73 -0.73275846E-82
```

Desired Output is: Each Block of Data written in its own column and the column starts with the "header" of each block, which is the first number. For example the last block should look like this:

```
0.18614378E-01 0.12050471E-12  0.44928328E-10  0.72404536E-10 0.37744496E-10  0.12066634E-12 0.25848493E-36 -0.13804858E-35  0.56376226E-83 0.20648121E-74 -0.89608567E-66 -0.20861629E-76 -0.87854256E-66 -0.23574755E-73 -0.73275846E-82
```

I thought about using AWK with FS=' ', but i don’t know how to tell my bash script to stop after reading 15 numbers and how to save those 15 numbers and output them into a separate file (using printf maybe?)

Thanks!

Comment: The question is highly unclear to me. 22 numbers? What I can see is a single number followed by 5 + 5 + 4 numbers (14). Neither the desired output is clear: 15 numbers per row?

Comment: i edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to write output in a single file, this is a bash one-liner that would work:

```
IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< $(cat results|tr -s ' ' |tr -d '\n'); while test "${#array[@]}" -ge "1"; do for i in {1..15}; do echo -n ${array[0]}; array=("${array[@]:1}"); done; echo; done > results_formatted
```

Comment: I added an `echo -n " "` after `echo -n ${array[0]}` to have a space inbetween each number. 
Can you explain  `array=("${array[@]:1}")` ?

Another Problem: My files have sizes around 25mb which make this approach very slow. Is it due to the read array command?

Comment: "${array[@]:1]" means elements of array starting at 1, while the array is 0 based, and we've just used element 0.
The speed, of course, we have to take into account that bash is a shell, it is not an "optimized data processing language interpreter". I'd always look at perl for something like this, my answer was just an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

If your data never has two lines near each other containing 1 column:

```
awk '{if(NF==1 && NR!=1){printf("\n%s",$0)} else{printf("%s",$0)}}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ t="" }NR>1 && NF==1{ print t > "file"++c; t="" }
     { t=(t!="")? sprintf("%s  %s",t,$0) : sprintf("%s",$0) }
     END{ if (t) print t > "file"++c }' file
```

Results:

```
> cat file1
0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
```

---

```
> cat file2
0.93071889E-02  0.14952319E-13  0.55746201E-11  0.89816722E-11  0.46833532E-11  0.14964636E-13  -0.92995325E-47  0.79969902E-46  0.00000000E+00 -0.21442451-105 -0.86924526E-93  0.00000000E+00 -0.85777333E-93  0.48179949-102  0.00000000E+00
```

---

```
> cat file3
0.18614378E-01  0.12050471E-12  0.44928328E-10  0.72404536E-10  0.37744496E-10  0.12066634E-12  0.25848493E-36 -0.13804858E-35  0.56376226E-83  0.20648121E-74 -0.89608567E-66  -0.20861629E-76 -0.87854256E-66 -0.23574755E-73 -0.73275846E-82
```